# Optimization: making a struct that uses different data types

Tags: c, design-patterns, data-structures, struct, embedded

Newbie C programmer here. I'm working on a math library in C and implementing some linear algebra stuff at the moment. The struct `Matrix` is defined as follows:

```c
typedef struct {
    double** mat;
    int nRows;
    int nCols;
} Matrix ;
```

I'm trying to optimize this part for an atmel ATMega16A deployment. This has around 1kB of SRAM and with a double array, I would only be able to store an 8x8 matrix at max in memory (or around 10 3x3 matrices with some space left over for other calculations). I realized that for most use cases, I don't need the `double` precision and can get by with using `float`.

**What is the right way of implementing a similar `struct` with a `float` array that occupies less space in memory?**

In an object-oriented environment, the right way of doing this would have been to create an abstract superclass `Matrix` and define various implementations (eg `MatrixDouble` and `MatrixFloat`). The same set of methods would then be able to do operations on both implementations. In this library, all the methods are currently returning `double` or `Matrix*` and accepting `Matrix*` arguments, and I don't want to do a complete rewrite of these methods and implement two methods for each procedure eg `double determinantDouble( MatrixDouble* mat )` and `float determinantFloat( MatrixFloat* mat )`.

Comment: The right way is to use C++, in C you will be either writing the same code twice or abusing the preprocessor.

Comment: You shouldn't be using floating point for ancient 8 bit microcontrollers to begin with. It has no FPU, so floating point will slaughter all that is performance, memory included.

Comment: @para This is an embedded system, so C++ is rarely ever the right choice (there either).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to realize that microcontroller programming is *very* different from PC programming. Microcontrollers are limited in pretty much every way possible, so it takes a more skill and care to program them, particularly legacy 8-bitters. (Why I recommend newbies to stay clear of 8-bitters, they are some of the hardest CPUs to program correctly in C.)

You must note that it is a very bad idea to use floating point types on 8 bit microcontrollers. They don't have any FPU, so you force the compiler to link in a relatively huge floating point software library, which will take up lots of memory and execution time.

[Please read this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/494924), in particular

> **When to use floating point**
>
> If your MCU has a FPU and you actually need to do advanced math, then you should use floating point. Otherwise you should not.

Generally, if you find yourself actually in need for floating point math, then you picked the wrong MCU for the task. You should have picked a Cortex M4 or bigger, with on-chip FPU.

---

To optimize the float type itself depending on target, one simple way is to do something like:

```
typedef float float_t;
```

And then change that type according to target with `#ifdef` compiler switches.

---

As for the struct itself, it doesn't make much sense to have variable dimensions on it, since you will never be able to afford that memory-wise. What you should do instead is to statically allocate a maximum size to cover the worst-case scenario.

Meaning something like

```
typedef struct {
  float mat[MAX_X][MAX_Y];
  uint8_t nRows;
  uint8_t nCols;
} Matrix ;
```

Where nRows/nCols mark how much of the matrix that is actually used.

(Please note that using `int` in an embedded system is almost always wrong. Instead use the `stdint.h` types to avoid signed types and to optimize for size. 8 bit MCUs dislike 16 bit arithmetic and hate 32 bit arithmetic, so stick to `uint8_t` whenever possible.)

Also make a habit of using *const correctness*, that is:

```
float_t determinantDouble (const Matrix* mat);
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'd recommend would be to lose the `type **` pointer. Instead just have `type *` and allocate/make it point to a memory area of size `sizeof(type) * nRows * nCols`. Having an additional level of pointers means you need to store `nRows` or `nCols` addresses on top of your actual data.

For making it the matrix more " type generic" in C, you might be able to define some macros:

```
#define Matrix_Type(type) \
    typedef struct {      \
        type *data;       \
        int nRows;        \
        int nCols;        \
    } Matrix_##type
```

Then:

```
 Matrix(float);
```

Would provide you a type definition for a matrix of floating point numbers named `Matrix_float`.
But you'd have to rework your whole library to have a bunch of macros instead of functions.
C does not have built-in type genericity, so you kinda have to craft it yourself...

Comment: This is the same as declaring two different struct types though.

Comment: It is, and that is what happens when you use C++ templated classes or Java generics. It generates more code for each possible type used.
It also makes sense because a Matrix of floats isn't really compatible with a matrix of doubles (or you would have to define what the result should be) and all their primitive take/return different data types.
And defining more types does not take more place in the resulting binary. The purpose is just to give semantics during compilation.

Comment: Another option would be to store the elements of your array as `void **data;`, maybe have a field `int elem_size;` so you can access the elements in an abstract manner, without knowing the type. But then, when doing operations on the actual elements, you'd need to have a way to know what is the type of elements in the matrix so you can cast them to the appropriate type.

Comment: Yeah but you are only going to have at most 2 float types so there's no point in abstraction, unless you want to make some super-generic matrix class... which is probably not something you'll ever need in a low-level embedded system.